# Sql query question

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle "(+)" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)

Can some one tell me what does (+) sign do in sql.. Thanks

```
a.sample_nbr = b.sample_nbr (+) and
a.sample_nbr = b.sub_sample_nbr (+) and
```

Comment: The correct answer to this question is *"They add confusion"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) - wikipedia is sometimes reliable.

The (+) after b.sample_nbr makes the "b" table optional. The query returns all tables, and where there are no corresponding constraint records, Oracle supplies a null in the constraint name column.

Comment: It can be used to specify a right outer join too.

Comment: Thanks +1 -> corrected the info and added details

Answer (score 2):

The plus sign in Oracle specifies an outer join.