# In Oracle SQL, what does PRIMARY_FLAG(+) = 'Y' do?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm looking at this chunk of SQL from a query:

```
AND CONT_POINT.CONTACT_POINT_TYPE(+) = 'EMAIL' 
AND CONT_POINT.PRIMARY_FLAG(+) = 'Y'
AND ra.cust_trx_type_id = rt.cust_trx_type_id
```

What is the   `PRIMARY_FLAG(+) = 'Y'` part for? thanks!!

edit: hmm , I think I've found a lead - [Oracle "(+)" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the old (pre-ANSI SQL) outer join operator.

In this particular usage, however, it's worth making an additional point.

If you have a query such as:

```
select a.name parent_name, 
       b.name child_name 
  from parent a,
       child b
 where a.id = b.id(+);
```

then you're going to show all the parent names, even those without children.  (That's what the (+) operator does.  If there are rows in parent that don't have any children, those rows will still be shown, with a NULL value for child_name.)

Now, what if you wanted to show parents, even those without children, but only female children?

If you do something like:

```
select a.name parent_name,
       b.name child_name
  from parent a,
       child b
 where a.id = b.id(+)
   and b.gender='F';
```

that would effectively invalidate the outer join.  Since any outer joined rows would have NULL for all the rows where no data is present in CHILD, the "b.gender='F'" would effectively cancel out the outer join, by filtering out the outer joined rows.

So, if instead, you do something like:

```
select a.name parent_name,
       b.name child_name
  from parent a,
       child b
 where a.id = b.id(+)
   and b.gender(+)='F';
```

That would give you the desired effect.  It would show only females for rows joined from PARENT to CHILD, and for rows w/ missing children, they would *not* be filtered out.

So, even though you didn't show the complete query, my guess is that you're outer joining to the table that has the PRIMARY_FLAG column, and this predicate is saying, show me all the rows where PRIMARY_KEY is 'Y' *or* PRIMARY_KEY is NULL due to outer join to a row that doesn't exist.

Hope that's clear.