# " (+) = " operator in oracle sql in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, operators

while changing stored procedure i came across (+) = operator. I have read [Oracle "(+)" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator) but seems like my problem is slightly different than one mentioned in that link.
So, can anyone please help me understand statement like:

```
select ....
from emp, dept 
where emp.dept_id (+) = dept.dept_id
```

why would they use both + and = sign while using this condition? I would be thankful if someone will help me with example or link where i can read about such operators.

Comment: This is the old Oracle syntax for left and right outer joins.  Learn the proper ANSI syntax and don't use this.  In fact, just avoid having commas in the `from` clause, and your queries will be better.

Comment: Oracle joins : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm

Comment: Thanks Gordon. are there any downsites of using commas in the oracle from clause?

Answer (score 1):

The `(+)=` operator refers to Oracle outer Joins wich simply extends the functionality of simple joins.

See the following [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm) on this operator and [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.1.2/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html) on how to use it with example

Answer (score 1):

This is the deprecated notation of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

The new and preferred notation according to the ANSI standard is:

```
select ....
from emp
left outer join dept 
on emp.dept_id = dept.dept_id
```