# Oracle's OUTER JOIN (+) on string - Migration PostgreSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, join, database-migration, outer-join

I'm migrating a client's software database from Oracle to PostgreSQL, and I have some trouble understanding a query, what it does, and consequently how to migrate it.

The query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL1, TBL2, TBL3, TBL4 
WHERE TBL3.Project_ID = TBL1.Project_ID 
 AND TBL2.Type_ID = TBL1.Type_ID 
 AND TBL4.PROPERTY_NAME(+)='Id' 
 AND TBL4.Entity_ID(+)=TBL1.Entity_ID
```

And the part I don't get, is the outer join (+) on 'Id'.
A join on a table, OK, but on a string? I've no idea of what it does.

Do someone has an idea?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4020794/3682599

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TBL4.PROPERTY_NAME(+)='Id'` means when the line was inner joined, then the value has to be *'Id'*, but when the line was outer joined, the condition is evaluated as true

however you should rewrite the statement to the standard as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL1
JOIN TBL2 ON TBL2.Type_ID = TBL1.Type_ID
JOIN TBL3 ON TBL3.Project_ID = TBL1.Project_ID
LEFT JOIN TBL4 ON TBL4.Entity_ID=TBL1.Entity_ID AND TBL4.PROPERTY_NAME='Id'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the equivalent of the following query using ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL1 t1
INNER JOIN TBL2 t2 ON (t1.Type_ID = t2.Type_ID)
INNER JOIN TBL3 t3 ON (t3.Project_ID = t1.Project_ID)
LEFT JOIN TBL4 t4 ON (t4.Entity_ID = t1.Entity_ID AND t4.PROPERTY_NAME = 'Id')
```

You're not joining to a string, merely specifying a join condition that's based on one.