# oracle sql query statement NVL not working as desired

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I am trying to learn oracle sql and below is my query. I wanted to print everyone's manager and if someone doesn't a manager then it should return "No One".

Problem: I am getting a blank statement instead of "No One". Any help?

```
SELECT NVL(m.first_name || ' '
    || m.last_name, 'No One') || ' supervises '
    || w.first_name || ' ' || w.last_name
  FROM employees w, employees m
 WHERE w.manager_id = m.employee_id(+);

NVL(M.FIRST_NAME||''||M.LAST_NAME,'NOONE')||'SUPERVISE
------------------------------------------------------
James Smith supervises Ron Johnson
Ron Johnson supervises Susan Jones
Ron Johnson supervises Fred Hobbs
  supervises James Smith
```

Comment: Read [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator) to learn more about the `(+)` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the reason, that when m.first_name and m.last_name will be null for the manager, then m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name will not result in null, but with ' '. So, it will print space instead of 'No One'. You can achieve your desired results by using nvl2 something like

```
SELECT NVL2( m.first_name ||m.last_name , m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name, 'No One' )
   || ' supervises '
   || w.first_name
   || ' '
   || w.last_name FROM employees w, employees m WHERE w.manager_id = m.employee_id(+);
```

Comment: I will mark your answer correct. Just wondering what does (+) in this query  (WHERE w.manager_id = m.employee_id(+)) stand for?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: yes as ideally I would have marked your answer right but I am a complete newbie and this answer is what I understood well. I will upvote your answer though. Just wondering what (+) does in my query.

Comment: This is oracle specific way for left outer join http://stackoverflow.com/a/4020794/2594724

Answer (score 1):

I believe the accepted answer can be simplified by recognizing that when an employee be unsupervised, there will be no matching record for his manager.  As a result, *both* the manager's first *and* last name will either be `NULL` or not `NULL` together.

```
SELECT NVL(m.first_name, 'No One', m.first_name || ' ' || m.last_name)
    || ' supervises ' || w.first_name || ' ' || w.last_name
FROM employees w LEFT JOIN employees m
    ON w.manager_id = m.employee_id
```

**Update:**

The `(+)` operator is Oracle's syntax for a `LEFT JOIN`.  Have a look at [this Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator) to learn more about Oracle's `(+)` operator.