# Oracle outer join syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
select *
from find fsc,
        let lf,
        cust cus,
        STRIKE ist
WHERE   fsc.id = lf.id
AND     ist.ID_old = fsc.ID_old
AND     lf.cust_id = cus.cust_id(+)
```

I know (+) is old syntax for a join, but I am not sure what it is actually doing to this query. Could someone explain this and show this query without the (+) in the where statement, using more modern join syntax?

Comment: the `(+)` is old syntax for an `OUTER JOIN` or a `LEFT JOIN` . Keeps all the records from the master table(The one without the plus sign) and all the matching records from the detail table(the one with the plus sign)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle "(+)" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
select *
from find fsc join
     let lf
     on fsc.id = lf.id join
     STRIKE ist
     on ist.ID_old = fsc.ID_old left join
     cust cus
     on lf.cust_id = cus.cust_id;
```

To be honest, the outer join is probably not necessary.  Why would `lf` have a `cust_id` that is not valid?  The only reasonable possibility is if the value is `NULL`.