# Conversion of Oracle join to Ansi join

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to convert the following Oracle SQL to ANSI SQL.

```
Select t1.c1, t2.c2, t1.c3 from t1, t2 where
T1.c1=t2.c1(+) and
T1.c2=t2.c2(+) and
T1.c3=t2.c3 and
T1.c4=t2.c4 and
T1.c1='1'
```

Comment: This is a faq. What does *the manual* say about (+)? What do the zillions of SO answers say? PS (Per your comment on an answer:) Read a *definition* of left join on: it returns inner join on rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle "(+)" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)

Answer (score 3):

This would be outer join if all columns in `t2` had the `(+)` modifier.

That would look like:

```
Select t1.c1, t2.c2, t1.c3
from t1 left join
     t2 
     on T1.c1 = t2.c1 and T1.c2 = t2.c2 and
        T1.c3 = t2.c3 and T1.c4 = t2.c4
where T1.c1 = '1';
```

However, your version is an inner join, because some of the columns do need to match -- so there needs to be a matching row in the second table.

So, the real equivalent is just:

```
Select t1.c1, t2.c2, t1.c3
from t1 join
     t2 
     on T1.c1 = t2.c1 and T1.c2 = t2.c2 and
        T1.c3 = t2.c3 and T1.c4 = t2.c4
where T1.c1 = '1';
```

And the `(+)` is not relevant.

Comment: Could you explain what the behavior is if only _some_ of the join conditions bear a `+` operator (I don't know this) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Ignore the `(+)` in that case.  The other columns need to match, which undoes the outer join.  By the way, your answer is technically correct, but the `WHERE` clause turns the outer join to an inner join.

Comment: Will the final answer contains rows for which c1 and c2 are null and c3 and c4 matched for t2 since for c1 and c2 left outer join is used?

Comment: @ShubhamShukla . . . The `(+)` operation (as far as I know) is not about matching `NULL` values to `NULL` values.  It is about adding new rows when there is not match in the other table.