# changing from old style to new style joins

Tags: sql, join, plsql, right-join

I have been trying to change my old style of SQL from cross to joins, but I can't manage to make it work.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT 'EFE' tipo,
    c.empnum,
    c.succlave,
    d.tipopago,
    d.tjcredito
FROM detcobros d,
    cobros c,
    masterbancos b,
    monedas m
WHERE     d.empnum = c.empnum
    AND d.succlave = c.succlave
    AND d.cobfolio = c.cobfolio
    AND d.PaisClave = b.PaisClave(+)
    AND d.bannum = b.bannum(+)
    AND d.monNum = m.monNum
    AND d.tipopago = 'EF'
    AND (   (c.status IN ('AU', 'US', 'UP'))
         OR (    c.status = 'CA'
             AND NVL (c.cortecaja, 0) <> NVL (c.cortecajacanc, 0)))
    AND c.empnum = 255
    AND c.succlave = 'CDCU'
    AND c.cortecaja = 3004
```

And here what I've tried:

```
SELECT 'EFE' tipo,
    c.empnum,
    c.succlave,
    d.tipopago,
    d.tjcredito
FROM detcobros d
    JOIN cobros c ON c.empnum   = d.empnum
    and c.succlave = d.succlave
    and c.cobfolio = d.cobfolio
    RIGHT JOIN masterbancos b ON b.PaisClave = d.PaisClave
    and  b.bannum    = d.bannum
    JOIN monedas m ON m.monNum  = d.monNum
WHERE d.tipopago = 'EF'
    AND (   (c.status IN ('AU', 'US', 'UP'))
         OR (    c.status = 'CA'
             AND NVL (c.cortecaja, 0) <> NVL (c.cortecajacanc, 0)))
    AND c.empnum = 255
    AND c.succlave = 'CDCU'
    AND c.cortecaja = 3004
```

The first query returns data but the second doesn't get any data.

Comment: To troubleshoot where you're breaking down, just do a `SELECT *` then remove your `JOIN`s and `WHERE`s until you find the one that's breaking your results. I would also say that you should move you `c.` conditions  up into the `JOIN` on `cobros c`, but I don't know what your data looks like. Think of the data in _sets_. What do you want to return from each table?

Comment: I'm not great with the old syntax, but I believe you wanted `LEFT JOIN` not `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: `JOIN monedas m ON m.monNum  = d.monNum` may be your problem.

Comment: thanks that did it the left join

Comment: do i have to do a double left join or with one is correct LEFT JOIN masterbancos b ON b.PaisClave = d.PaisClave
    LEFT JOIN masterbancos b.bannum    = d.bannum

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. I misread the original query. The `JOIN` on `monedas` is correct. It should be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `masterbancos` instead of a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, since the original criteria had the `(+)` on the `b.` columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with LEFT JOIN because the + operator is on the right.

[syntax + operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)

Comment: Perhaps this could be made clearer, as `d.PaisClave = b.PaisClave(+)` is the same thing as `b.PaisClave(+) = d.PaisClave` (the latter is more logical, but for some reason writing joins backwards is a popular anti-pattern).

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned above, think of your data in the sets of data that you want to get from each table.

Essentially, a SQL engine will process your query in the following basic order:

`FROM (incl JOINs) -> CONNECT BY -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY`

For your query, I would recommend moving all of your relevant conditions up into your `JOIN`s to minimize the sets of data that will be `JOIN`ed together.

I would recommend:

```
SELECT 'EFE' AS tipo
    , c.empnum
    , c.succlave
    , d.tipopago
    , d.tjcredito
FROM detcobros d
INNER JOIN cobros c ON d.empnum = c.empnum
    AND d.succlave = c.succlave
    AND d.cobfolio = c.cobfolio
    AND c.empnum = 255
    AND c.succlave = 'CDCU'
    AND c.cortecaja = 3004
    AND (   
          c.status IN ('AU', 'US', 'UP')
          OR (
              c.status = 'CA'
              AND NVL (c.cortecaja, 0) <> NVL (c.cortecajacanc, 0)
          )
    )
LEFT OUTER JOIN masterbancos b ON d.PaisClave = b.PaisClave
    AND d.bannum = b.bannum
INNER JOIN monedas m ON d.monNum = m.monNum
WHERE d.tipopago = 'EF'
```

This does include some of my own personal preferences (like using `AS` in `SELECT` column aliases but not in table aliases. Also, I believe your query broke on `JOIN monedas m ON m.monNum = d.monNum`. You specified two different types of `JOIN`s between the queries.

Comment: I would add that moving the `JOIN` conditions from the `WHERE` to the `JOIN` probably won't have an effect for `INNER JOIN`s but may change the results on `OUTER JOIN`s. See my above list of order of execution to work towards what exactly data it is that you need returned.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I got:

```
select 'EFE' tipo
     , c.empnum
     , c.succlave
     , d.tipopago
     , d.tjcredito
from   cobros c
       join detcobros d
            on   d.empnum = c.empnum
            and  d.succlave = c.succlave
            and  d.cobfolio = c.cobfolio
       join monedas m
            and  m.monnum = d.monnum
       left join masterbancos b
            and  b.paisclave = d.paisclave
            and  b.bannum = d.bannum
where  c.empnum = 255
and    c.succlave = 'CDCU'
and    c.cortecaja = 3004
and    d.tipopago = 'EF'
and    (   (c.status in ('AU', 'US', 'UP'))
        or (c.status = 'CA' and nvl(c.cortecaja, 0) <> nvl(c.cortecajacanc, 0)) );
```

My personal preference is to place the outer joins at the end of the `from` clause. Also the keywords `outer` and `inner` are redundant clutter so I never use them.

`cobros` seemed to be the logical starting place as it has the most predicates in the `where` clause. (The optimiser doesn't care, of course.)

A right join is just a left join written backwards. I never use them, I just arrange the tables the other (normal) way around.

The filtering conditions remain in the `where` clause (unless they apply to an outer join in which case they need to be included in the join - but there weren't any like that here). I'm sure this can be argued either way, but I like to see joins and filtering conditions listed separately.

I've also fixed your old-style uppercase for you ;)

Comment: `outer` is not clutter when used with a `full outer join` which is not relevant to this particular question but to say one "never" uses `outer` is not a certainty.

Comment: Now that I check, the `outer` keyword is optional in `full join` as well. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm

Comment: Thanks @William - learning something new every day is a good thing.