# What is the meaning of (+) in a WHERE in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope that someone could help me. I  know this:

```
SELECT A.IDTABLAA, B.NOMBRETABLAB
FROM TABLA_A A, TABLA_B B
WHERE A.IDTABLAA=B.IDTABLAB(+)
```

The WHERE here is equivalent to a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but I don't know what means when the (+) symbols is in other place, like this:

```
WHERE 1=1
AND A.IDA = B.IDB
AND A.TAB(+) = 'E'
```

What is the meaning of this?

Comment: It means someone is using archaic Oracle syntax and should learn how to properly use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/left-and-right-joins-using-the-plus-sign-in-oracle/

Comment: I think this SO question is relevant: [Oracle “(+)” Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)