# SQL convert from Oracle to ANSI JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join, ansi-sql

How to convert from old Oracle join type to ANSI joins and why?

```
SELECT *
FROM a, b, c
WHERE b.id (+) = a.id1
AND b.xxx = c.yyy
AND c.id (+) = a.id2
```

--Should be this 1?

```
select * from
A
left outer join B on B.ID = A.ID1
left outer join C on C.ID = A.ID2 AND B.xxx = C.yyy
```

--or this 2?

```
select * from
A
left outer join C on C.ID = A.ID2
left outer join B on B.ID = A.ID1 AND B.xxx = C.yyy
```

Comment: The *challenge* with such queries is not to rewrite them in ANSI, but to realize what *was the idea* while writing the query.

Comment: Why would it be either one? Right now you are just asking us to rewrite the manual with no idea where you are stuck understanding it. Moreover this can be expected to be a faq. [ask] [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle "(+)" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020786/oracle-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm):

> If the WHERE clause contains a condition that compares a column from table B with a constant, then the (+) operator must be applied to the column so that Oracle returns the rows from table A for which it has generated nulls for this column. Otherwise Oracle returns only the results of a simple join.

So there is an inner join between `b` and `c`.  And because of the overall conditions, this is going to turn all the joins into `INNER JOIN` (there needs to be valid values in `b` and `c` for that condition to work.

I think the equivalent logic is:

```
SELECT *
FROM a JOIN
     b
     ON b.id = a.id1 JOIN
     c
     ON c.id = a.id2 AND b.xxx = c.yyyy;
```

That is, the simple equality eliminates turns the outer joins into inner joins.

Of course, you can test this.

Answer (score 4):

You can also *cheat* by using Oracle SQL Developer.

Paste in your ANSI SQL query or Oracle SQL Query, select it, right click, and use the convert feature.

The SQL parser will rewrite the JOINS for you.

So this would be for any query, not just the one you have in your question/scenario.

You should of course check the execution plans and data returned by the queries to make sure they are functionally equivalent.

[image]

Comment: While the functionality appears useful, the query the animation shows is incorrect as the result should be `INNER JOIN`s and not `LEFT JOIN`s. If you wanted an intermediate step then you could go for `SELECT * FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON b.ID = a.ID1
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON c.ID = a.ID2 WHERE B.xxx = C.yyy;` [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3SNuaVpa) but the `WHERE` clause would still convert the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s to `INNER JOIN`s.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your options:

```sql
select *
from   A
       left outer join B on B.ID = A.ID1
       left outer join C on C.ID = A.ID2 AND B.xxx = C.yyy
```

Would be written as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a, b, c
WHERE b.id (+) = a.id1
AND   b.xxx = c.yyy (+)
AND   c.id (+) = a.id2
```

---

and:

```sql
select *
from   A
       left outer join C on C.ID = A.ID2
       left outer join B on B.ID = A.ID1 AND B.xxx = C.yyy
```

Would be written as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a, b, c
WHERE b.id (+) = a.id1
AND   b.xxx (+) = c.yyy
AND   c.id (+) = a.id2
```

---

What you have is:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a
       INNER JOIN b ON (a.id1 = b.id)
       INNER JOIN c ON (a.id2 = c.id AND b.xxx = c.yyy)
```

> why?

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a, b, c
WHERE  b.id (+) = a.id1
AND    b.xxx = c.yyy
AND    c.id (+) = a.id2
```

The line:

```sql
AND    b.xxx = c.yyy
```

Requires that there is a `b` and a `c` row; this will not occur when there is a left-outer join so the join is the equivalent of an inner join and the query could be rewritten as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a, b, c
WHERE  b.id = a.id1
AND    b.xxx = c.yyy
AND    c.id = a.id2
```

And all then it is clearer that all the joins are inner joins.

---

What you may have intended to write was:

```sql
select *
from   A,
       (
         SELECT b.id AS b_id,
                c.id AS c_id,
                b.xxx,
                c.yyy
         FROM   b, c
         WHERE  b.xxx = c.yyy
       ) bc
WHERE  bc.b_id (+) = a.id1
AND    bc.c_id (+) = a.id2
```

Which would be:

```sql
select *
from   A
       left outer join (
         SELECT b.id AS b_id,
                c.id AS c_id,
                b.xxx,
                c.yyy
         FROM   b
                INNER JOIN c ON b.xxx = c.yyy
       ) bc
       on bc.b_id = a.id1 AND bc.c_id = a.id2
```

or, using parentheses in the join to set the precedence of the joins:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         b
         INNER JOIN c
         ON b.xxx = c.yyy
       )
       ON b.id = a.id1 AND c.id = a.id2
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/REZJ_mxD)*

Answer (score 0):

If you run simple `explain plan` and check the result, you may see that it generates two `inner join`s:

> ```
> explain plan set statement_id = 'test' for
> SELECT *
> FROM a, b, c
> WHERE
> b.id (+) = a.id1
> AND b.xxx = c.yyy
> AND c.id (+) = a.id2
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table(dbms_xplan.display(null, 'test'))
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                            |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 1502482080                                                  |
> |                                                                              |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |     1 |    78 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  1 |  HASH JOIN          |      |     1 |    78 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |      |     1 |    52 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | C    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                              |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                          |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                          |
> |                                                                              |
> |    1 - access("B"."XXX"="C"."YYY" AND "C"."ID"="A"."ID2")                    |
> |    2 - access("B"."ID"="A"."ID1")                                            |
> |                                                                              |
> | Note                                                                         |
> | -----                                                                        |
> |    - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)                     |
> ```

> ```
> explain plan set statement_id = 'test1' for
> select *
> from a
>   left join b
>     on b.id = a.id1
>   left join c
>     on c.id = a.id2
>     and b.xxx = c.yyy
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from table(dbms_xplan.display(null, 'test1'))
> ```
>
> ```
> | PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                            |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | Plan hash value: 2316364204                                                  |
> |                                                                              |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | | Id  | Operation           | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |      |     1 |    78 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER    |      |     1 |    78 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER   |      |     1 |    52 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| A    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| B    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | |   5 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL | C    |     1 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | |
> | ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> |                                                                              |
> | Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                          |
> | ---------------------------------------------------                          |
> |                                                                              |
> |    1 - access("C"."ID"(+)="A"."ID2" AND "B"."XXX"="C"."YYY"(+))              |
> |    2 - access("B"."ID"(+)="A"."ID1")                                         |
> |                                                                              |
> | Note                                                                         |
> | -----                                                                        |
> |    - dynamic statistics used: dynamic sampling (level=2)                     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c1f87da9248422bcfcf711cf9b7f3acf)*