# Oracle Query not giving result though outer join is present

Tags: syntax, oracle11g, outer-join

In the below query when i comment one line AND EVT.EVT_EVNT_ID(+) = DPT.DPT_EVNT_ID or add outer join (+) in one line AND EVT.EVT_ENTITY_ID ='G' the query will fetch results, else it will not give any results.
`

```
select *         from 
    (select B11.ext_db_id,B11.FRST_LINE_OF_PRFRD_NAME, E11.*, D1.D1_evnt_id,    
        (SELECT E1.E1_DT
           FROM  S1core.E1_EVNT_DT_DTLS E1
          WHERE E1.E1_ENTITY_ID = D1.D1_ENTITY_ID
          AND E1.E1_EVNT_ID     = D1.D1_EVNT_ID
          AND E1.E1_D1_ID      = D1.D1_D1_ID
          AND E1.E1_DT_TYP      = 'MEET'
          AND E1.E1_OPTN_SEQ_N  = '999'
          AND E1.STATUS          = 'AUTHD' ) "MEET_DATE"
         FROM  S1core.E1_EVNT_DT_DTLS E11,  S1core.SECURITY_ACCOUNT SFA,
         S1core.EXTRNL_SYS_DETAILS EXT,
         S1core.D1_DPOT_EVNT_DTLS D1,  S1core.IP_ACNT_RELATION i1,
         S1core.ELG_ELGBLTY E1,S1core.P1_D1_PRXY_DTLS P1, S1core.EVT_DTLS   EVT,
         S1core.BUSINESS_PARTNER B1, S1core.BUSINESS_PARTNER B11
        WHERE
        P1.P1_EVNT_ID(+)     = D1.D1_EVNT_ID                   
        AND B1.BP_ID          = i1.IP_ID
        AND SFA.BP_ID          = B11.BP_ID
        AND B11.OWNER_ENTITY  =  SFA.OWNER_ENTITY
        AND P1.P1_D1_ID(+)   = D1.D1_D1_ID
       AND P1.P1_ENTITY_ID(+) = D1.D1_ENTITY_ID
        AND P1.STATUS(+)        = 'AUTHD'
        AND EXT.LVL_REF    =    SFA.SCA_REF
        AND EXT.OWNER_ENTITY  =  SFA.owner_entity
        AND EXT.EXTRNL_SYS_ID  = '39'
        AND EXT.BP_ID = SFA.BP_ID
        AND EXT.LVL = 5
        AND E1.ELG_SEC_ID            = D1.D1_SEC_ID
        AND D1.D1_ENTITY_ID        = E1.ELG_ENTITY_ID
        AND D1.D1_EVNT_ID          = E1.ELG_EVNT_ID
        AND D1.D1_D1_ID           = E1.ELG_D1_ID
        AND E1.ELG_ENTITY_ID         = SFA.OWNER_ENTITY
        AND E1.ELG_ACNT_ID           = SFA.SCA_REF
        AND i1.owner_entity        = SFA.OWNER_ENTITY
        AND i1.owner_entity        = B1.OWNER_ENTITY
        AND i1.SCA_REF  = SFA.SCA_REF
        AND i1.stat              <> 2
        AND EVT.EVT_ENTITY_ID      ='G'
        AND EVT.EVT_EVNT_ID(+)       = D1.D1_EVNT_ID
        AND EVT.STATUS(+)            = 'AUTHD'
        AND E11.E1_ENTITY_ID       = D1.D1_ENTITY_ID
        AND E11.E1_EVNT_ID         = D1.D1_EVNT_ID
        AND E11.E1_D1_ID          = D1.D1_D1_ID
        AND D1.D1_EVNT_GRP         = 'MEETING'
        AND E1.ELG_FNL_ELGBL_QNTTY   > 0
        AND D1.D1_ENTITY_ID        = 'GSSIN' -- P_D1_ENTITY_ID
        AND B11.ext_db_id LIKE 'LICMF' -- P_GLOBAL_CUSTODIAN
         AND B1.ext_db_id LIKE '%' -- P_FUND_MANAGER
         AND SUBSTR(EXT.LEVEL_EXTNL_SYS,1,5) LIKE '%' -- P_SUB_ACCOUNT_ID
         AND SUBSTR(EXT.LEVEL_EXTNL_SYS,6,9) LIKE '%' -- P_SCHEMA_ID
         AND SUBSTR( D1.D1_EVNT_TYP, 1, 4 ) LIKE '%' -- P_EVENT_TYPE
        AND E11.E1_DT_TYP = 'MEET'
        and D1.D1_evnt_id='12457886544'
       AND D1.OU_ID  IN('17','80') -- ('S1 INDIA PC')
       ) ;
```

Am I missing any outer join or the query is having any other issue as i can see that dpt_evnt_id='12457886544'is available in all tables.

`

I tried to run this query by commenting  AND EVT.EVT_EVNT_ID(+) = DPT.DPT_EVNT_ID
and by adding outer join in  EVT.EVT_ENTITY_ID (+)     ='G'

Comment: [mre] This is way too much code. [ask] [Help] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) PS [Oracle "(+)" Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020786/3404097) [Left Join With Where Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4752455/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```sql
AND EVT.EVT_ENTITY_ID  ='G'
AND EVT.EVT_EVNT_ID(+) = D1.D1_EVNT_ID
AND EVT.STATUS(+)      = 'AUTHD'
```

Even though the second two have `(+)` the first one does not so the join to `EVT` will be treated as an `INNER JOIN` and not an `OUTER JOIN`.

You should convert your code to use ANSI joins as it will be much easier to spot issues like this.

*Note: There may be more issues like this. However, your code has so many joins, the syntax is archaic, and we have no way of validating the correctness that I stopped looking after finding the first issue. You are going to need to debug it all to check for any other issues.*