# how to outer-join Tables using ANSI sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on 2 Tables.  One contains 657 rows matching my filter criteria, and the other contains 193 records.

I successfully joined them using Oracle's "AFAIK" syntax:

```
select
  ecp.portfolio_acct, ecp.posn_id cost_posn_id, ecp.asset_id 
from MID_COST_POSITION ecp, MID_CASH_POSITION cas
where ecp.portfolio_acct = 10183306
  and ecp.portfolio_acct = cas.portfolio_acct(+)
  and ecp.asset_id       = cas.asset_id(+)
;
```

However, I cannot seem to replicate these results using ANSI-SQL (or, ISO-sql):

```
select
  ecp.portfolio_acct, ecp.posn_id cost_posn_id, ecp.asset_id 
from MID_COST_POSITION ecp
LEFT OUTER JOIN MID_CASH_POSITION cas
  on ecp.portfolio_acct = cas.portfolio_acct
where ecp.asset_id      = cas.asset_id
  and ecp.portfolio_acct = 10183306 
;
```

I have tried various JOINs without success.  In the 1st example I had to Outer Join 2 separate fields, which I do not know how to accomplish using ANSI-SQL.

I appreciate any guidance anyone can offer.  Thank you!

Comment: The link to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001045/how-do-i-convert-a-legacy-left-outer-join-statement-in-oracle gave me the answer I need.  The order of "ON", "AND", and "WHERE" clauses quite definitely make a difference.


    select  ecp.portfolio_acct, ecp.posn_id cost_posn_id, ecp.asset_id 
    from MID_COST_POSITION ecp
    LEFT JOIN MID_CASH_POSITION cas
        on cas.asset_id = ecp.asset_id
      and ecp.portfolio_acct = cas.portfolio_acct
    where ecp.portfolio_acct = 10183306
    order by 1, 3;

Answer (score 3):

```
select
  ecp.portfolio_acct, ecp.posn_id cost_posn_id, ecp.asset_id 
from MID_COST_POSITION ecp
LEFT OUTER JOIN MID_CASH_POSITION cas
  on ecp.portfolio_acct = cas.portfolio_acct
and ecp.asset_id      = cas.asset_id
Where ecp.portfolio_acct = 10183306 
;
```

You were turning this into an inner join with the following where condition because it now has to meet that condition in the result set:

```
ecp.asset_id      = cas.asset_id
```

Comment: Yes, I see it now.  The Filter Criteria order is quite important!

Comment: This helps explain it: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/WHERE_conditions_on_a_LEFT_JOIN