# Select entries by where from different tables

Tags: sql, multiple-tables

I have two tables:

table "data"

```
 id        int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 name      varchar(200),
 remark    varchar(200),
```

table "tags"

```
 id        int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 macro     varchar(200),
 value     varchar(200),
 data_id   int(11)
```

One entry in "data" can have zero or more entries in "tags" which are connected by "data_id" (reference to "data.id").

Now I want to search for all entries in "data" with some WHERE condition from both tables (entries that also a match in tags key/value).

```
SELECT data.id,data.name 
FROM data,tags 
WHERE (data.name LIKE ?) 
   or (data.remark LIKE ?) 
   or (tags.value LIKE ?) ...
```

How to do this nested query?

THANKS

Comment: [How do I convert a “legacy” TO left outer join statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001045/how-do-i-convert-a-legacy-left-outer-join-statement-in-oracle)

Comment: You do not explain why the result are not the ones you expect....

Comment: Please supply sample data and desired results.  [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query with data from two tables need to make use of a `JOIN` clause

Your query will look like:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM data AS d
    JOIN tags AS t ON t.data_id = d.id
WHERE (d.name LIKE ?) 
   or (d.remark LIKE ?) 
   or (t.value LIKE ?) ...
```

It's worth noting that this query will select only the `data` that has at least one `tag`. If you need the `data` even if there's no `tag` associated you could do:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM data AS d
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tags AS t ON t.data_id = d.id
WHERE (d.name LIKE ?) 
   OR (d.remark LIKE ?)
   OR (t.value LIKE ?) ...
```

You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752455/left-join-with-where-clause#4752507).

Comment: The OP is describing a `left outer join` scenario

Comment: @Stu Wouldn't `"WHERE condition from both tables"` imply a `INNER JOIN`? Regardless, I'll expand the answer.

Comment: The condition is `or` not `and`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `exists`:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM data d
WHERE d.name LIKE ? OR
      d.remark LIKE ? OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tags t WHERE t.data_id = d.id AND t.value LIKE ?);
```

For performance, you want an index on `tags(data_id, value)`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tag_data_id_value on tags(data_id, value);
```

Expressing this as a `LEFT JOIN` is rather tricky.  Assuming that only one tag would match per data, it would be:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name 
FROM data d LEFT JOIN
     tags t
     ON t.data_id = d.id AND t.value LIKE ?
WHERE d.name LIKE ? OR
      d.remark LIKE ? OR
      t.data_id IS NOT NULL;
```

However, this can return duplicate data ids if multiple tags match the same data id.  I recommend `EXISTS`.

Comment: Hello everybody,
THANKS for all the hints for my problem.
The idea with the EXISTS seems to be the simplest one and also (with the extra SELECT) the most powerfull.

THANKS to @gordon-linoff

Comment: I just tried this with a sample database (with random data): aprox 1000 `data` entries and 15000 `tags` entries.
The `EXISTS` query seems to be very slow...
:-(

Comment: @devtry . . . You want an index to support `EXISTS`.

Comment: what do you mean with "you want an index"?

Comment: @devtry . . . I modified the answer already to point out the index you want.

Comment: "For performance, you want an index on tags(data_id, value)"
Sorry, I do not unterstand. What/how to add?